# How to realize a two step authentication with HTTP AUTH and FOSUserbundle?

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, authentication, mod-rewrite, fosuserbundle

I need to secure my whole web site (because it's in development). To achieve this, I want to put a simple HTTP Auth with static credentials in front of the whole web site. The user should not be able to see anything without entering the correct data.

I could use the .htaccess file, but the problem is that I have one VIRTUAL directory "/api" (using mod_rewrite) that I want to secure with another password / user combination. So I cannot simply put a .htaccess under /api that disables the general HTTP auth and enables another one.

So I have to do it with the Symfony2 security component. But I have absolutely no idea how.

Another problem is that I am using the FOSUserBundle. ==> I want the HTTP auth to be independent from the FOSUserBundle login. After entering the user / password of the HTTP auth, the user should not be logged in. He should be acting as a normal guest until he uses the FOSUserBundle login form.

Is there any way to do this in Symfony2?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is put in your `security.yml` something like this:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        basic_secured_area:
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Demo Area"
        fos_authentication:
            pattern: ^/
            #here you configure your FOSUserBundle security

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    ryan:  { password: ryanpass, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
                    admin: { password: kitten, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
```

This will secure whole site because of url `pattern: ^/` with http basic security. This is separate security than `FOSUserBundle`, authenticating in http basic won't make you logged in your `FOSUserBundle`.

Find complete guide [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already read the guide you linked and I already tried a solution similar to yours. But this is not working!

I can login via http basic like I want. But if I do this, I get automatically logged in in FOSUserBundle with my http auth user (wich btw does not exist in my user database)

Comment: Okay, I am getting really pissed off now. The security component of Symfony2 is very bad documented. So I'll not waste any more time on it. I am looking for a pure apache2 solution now. This should be easier...